# Run config clear on browser

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I need to run `php artisan config:clear` on my app that is online, the only issue is that I have only the FTP credentials and DB, and not the SSH to run on the terminal, how can I run this command without the terminal?
Already tried looking on the forum and didn't found any question related with my issue but didn't found any answer for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call the artisan command from anywhere in your PHP code block.

```
$exitCode = Artisan::call('config:clear');
```

More info can be found here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands

Answer (score 0):

That artisan command is only a helper to let you clear out the cached files.

You should be able to clear the config cache yourself, by removing the file config.php from folder /bootstrap/cache/ in your project.